# How do delete highlighted text in a command line

Tags: macos, terminal

So I was trying to delete a portion of a command line command, but when I type backspace(delete option), it merely deselect the portion rather than delete the selected text as I expected. Is there a shortcut to use in the command line to delete the portion of the command that has been highlighted(selected?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Terminal doesn't really care what you have selected, other than you can copy selected - it uses the cursor position for operations.

<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>→</kbd>  or  <kbd>←</kbd>  will jump the cursor one word at a time
 <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>  will delete the word immediately left of the cursor
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd>  or  <kbd>E</kbd>  will take you to the beginning or end of a line
 <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>U</kbd>  will delete to the beginning of the line
 <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>  will delete to the end of the line

There are many more - see [TechRepublic - 20 Terminal shortcuts developers need to know](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/20-terminal-shortcuts-developers-need-to-know/)